# Error when trying to mount MTD device from Linux

Tags: linux, flash-memory

How do I mount an MTD device from Linux?  The mount command is failing, see below:

```
[root@10 ~]# cat /proc/mtd
dev:    size   erasesize  name
mtd0: 00400000 00080000 "UBoot"
mtd1: 00400000 00080000 "UImage"
mtd2: 3f800000 00080000 "Root"
[root@10 ~]# cat /proc/filesystems
nodev   sysfs
nodev   rootfs
nodev   bdev
nodev   proc
nodev   tmpfs
nodev   devtmpfs
nodev   sockfs
nodev   usbfs
nodev   pipefs
nodev   anon_inodefs
nodev   rpc_pipefs
nodev   devpts
        ext3
        ext2
        ext4
        squashfs
nodev   ramfs
        vfat
        msdos
        iso9660
nodev   nfs
nodev   jffs2
        xfs
nodev   mtd_inodefs
nodev   oprofilefs
nodev   ubifs
[root@10 ~]# mount -t ubifs /dev/mtdblock2 /mnt/flash
UBIFS error (pid 631): ubifs_get_sb: cannot open "/dev/mtdblock2", error -22
mount: mounting /dev/mtdblock2 on /mnt/flash failed: Invalid argument
[root@10 ~]# uname -a
Linux 10.140.9.57 2.6.35.9 #12 Thu Aug 23 22:13:28 EDT 2012 armv7l Marvell PJ4Bv7 Processor�� rev 1 (v7l) Marvell Armada-370 GNU/Linux
[root@10 ~]#
```